# Split once function in lua

Tags: string, function, split, lua

I want to split a string only once so the output looks like this:

```
STRING1: STRING.STRING1.STRING2

OUT1: STRING
OUT2: STRING1.STRING2
```

I tried to make a function since I can't find a function that someone else made, and it kind of worked. For some reason, if you set the separator to `"."` then the function completely stops working and sets the default start and end values to `1, 1` Because of this my current output is:

```
STRING1: STRING.STRING1.STRING2

OUT1: 
OUT2: TRING.STRING1.STRING2
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong in this function:

```
function splitOnce(inputstr, sep)
    local s, e = inputstr:find(sep)

    local t = {}

    --print(inputstr)
    --print(sep)
    --print("start: "..tostring(s)..", end: "..tostring(e))

    table.insert(t, inputstr:sub(1, s - 1))
    table.insert(t, inputstr:sub(e + 1, -1))

    return t
end
```

Comment: `find(sep, 1, true)`

Comment: I tried yours, it returned `nil` with the separator `"."`

Comment: `string.find("STRING1: STRING.STRING1.STRING2", ".", 1, true)` returns `16 16` not `nil`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [match](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.match) to separate the string using a pattern with 2 captures.
Here I use `(.-)%".. sep .."(.+)` where `.-` will catch the shortest possible string before the separator and `.+` will catch everything left after it.

One limitation of this method is the separate is escaped, so if you use a separate such as `d`, `w`, or another letter that is a magic char in a patter it will not work as expected, it should work for all single char punctuation separators though.

```lua
function splitOnce(inputstr, sep)
    local prefix, suffix = inputstr:match("(.-)%".. sep .."(.+)")

    local t = {}

    print(inputstr)
    print(sep)
    print("prefix: "..tostring(prefix)..", suffix: "..tostring(suffix))

    table.insert(t, prefix)
    table.insert(t, suffix)

    return t
end

splitOnce("STRING.STRING1.STRING2", ".")
```

output

> STRING.STRING1.STRING2
>
> .
>
> prefix: STRING, suffix: STRING1.STRING2